# "Дерганый" ввод координат при перетаскивании

Tags: libgdx

Делаю ККИ под андроид. Сам проект является учебным. В основном использую stage2d и все от него производное. У меня есть класс GameBoard, наследуемый от Stage, который я использую как InputProcessor. Также есть класс CardContainer, наследуемый от Actor и имеющий в себе внутренний класс, наследуемый от InputListener. Экземпляр данного внутреннего класса я и назначаю в качестве Listener'а для CardContainer. Проблема в том, что при событии dragged экземпляр CardContainer начинает при малейшем перетаскивание перемещаться в странную точку на экране, а потом обратно на место tap'а при еще одном малейшем сдвиге. Вот лог координат:

`26.648193 42.579475
639.7796 104.03359
23.173706 43.941795
636.73944 105.39596
21.002136 45.30413
635.0022 105.850075`

Далее классы.
CardGame:

```
public class CardGame implements ApplicationListener {
SpriteBatch batch;
Texture img, backGround;
static GameBoard gameBoard;
StretchViewport stretchViewport;
Player player;

public static GameBoard getGameBoard(){
    return gameBoard;
}

@Override
public void create (){
    System.out.println(DeckTransportClass.text);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    //img = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
    backGround = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("whiteBackGround.png"));

    stretchViewport = new StretchViewport(800/*Gdx.graphics.getWidth()*/, 480/*Gdx.graphics.getHeight()*/);
    stretchViewport.update(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), true);
    gameBoard = new GameBoard(stretchViewport, batch);
    //InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer();
    //Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
    //multiplexer.addProcessor(gameBoard);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gameBoard);

    gameBoard.startGame();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    //gameBoard.getViewport().update(width, height, false);
    gameBoard.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gameBoard.draw();
    gameBoard.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void dispose () {
    batch.dispose();
    backGround.dispose();
    gameBoard.dispose();
}
}
```

CardContainerListener:

```
    protected class CardContainerListener extends InputListener{
    private float offSetX;
    private float offSetY;
    private float sizeX;
    private float sizeY;

    protected CardContainer cardContainer;

    public CardContainerListener(CardContainer cardContainer){
        this.cardContainer = cardContainer;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        //return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        if(CardGame.gameBoard.getAttacker() == cardField.getPlayer()) {
            SizeToAction sAction = new SizeToAction();
            MoveByAction mAction = new MoveByAction();
            event.getListenerActor().setZIndex(10);
            event.getListenerActor().getParent().setZIndex(10);
            offSetX = x;
            offSetY = y;
            sizeX = event.getListenerActor().getWidth();
            sizeY = event.getListenerActor().getHeight();
            sAction.setSize((int) (60 + 60 * 0.1), (int) (90 + 90 * 0.1));
            sAction.setDuration(0.05f);
            mAction.setAmount(-60 * 0.05f, -90 * 0.05f);
            mAction.setDuration(0.05f);
            event.getListenerActor().addAction(sAction);
            event.getListenerActor().addAction(mAction);
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
        super.touchDragged(event, x, y, pointer);
        //x = Gdx.input.getX()/* * (float)Math.cos(cardField.getRotation())*/;
        //y = (-Gdx.input.getY() + 480)/* * (float)Math.cos(cardField.getRotation())*/;
        event.getListenerActor().setPosition(x - offSetX - cardField.getX(), y - offSetY - cardField.getY());
        System.out.println(x + " " + y);
    }

    @Override
    public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
        //super.touchUp(event, x, y, pointer, button);
        event.getListenerActor().setZIndex(1);
        if(event.getListenerActor().getParent() != null) event.getListenerActor().getParent().setZIndex(1);
        event.getListenerActor().setSize(60,90);
        cardField.setContainers();
    }
}
```

Извиняюсь за говнокод. Если что-то надо - пишите.

Comment: Если что, CardGame - главный класс, а CardContainerListener является тем самым внутренним классом в CardContainer